# Are the shortcuts stored in a file in IntelliJ/Eclipse?

Tags: eclipse, intellij-idea, intellij-14

I have customized keyboard shortcuts on my personal computer. So, if I am moving away from my machine, I would like to take this shortcuts file with me.

Am I making some sense here?

Answer (score 1):

Yes they are stored locally in a file.

You better use File > Export Settings and check what you want to be exported (key 
map, etc).

Then on the other machine use File > Import Settings

Comment: You are awesome, Thanks. That's as simple as possible.

Answer (score 0):

On Eclipse, you can use the following steps to Export & Import.

Export using **File -> Export -> General -> Preferences -> Keys Preferences**
It will generate a .epf file (Eclipse Prefrences File)

Import the file saved in previous step, using **File -> Import -> General -> Preferences -> Keys Preferences**